# MySQL-PHP-XML output

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm a relatively inexperienced programmer trying to work through a current project. Basically, I'm designing a feature for a database; using a search query someone will be able to have that information inserted into a form letter. At this point, I'm trying to translate the results from the search into xml format using XMLWriter, unfortunately the search page isn't even being generated anymore. I'm using code based on a solution offered I've included the php code below, any and all feedback would be welcome

```
    <?php 

    session_start(); 
    include 'conn.php'; 

    if(empty($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['password'])) 
        print("Access to database denied"); 
    else { 
        $username = $_SESSION['username']; 
        $password = $_SESSION['password']; 
        $type = $_SESSION['type']; 

        if($type == "admin") { 
            include '../includes/aheader.html'; 
        } 
        if($type == "user") { 
            include '../includes/uheader.html'; 
        } 
        if(isset($_POST["searchButton"])) { 
            $keyword = $_POST['keyword']; 
            $choice = $_POST['choice'];

        if($choice == "company_name") 
            $sql = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE company_name LIKE ?"); 

        if($choice == "project_code") 
            $sql = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE project_code LIKE ?"); 

        $keyword = '%'.$keyword.'%'; 
        $sql -> bind_param('s', $keyword); 
        $sql -> execute(); 
        $result = $sql -> get_result(); 

        if(!$result) 
                print("<p>Select query failed</p>"); 
            else { 
        if($result -> num_rows == 0) 
                print("<p>No match found</p>");
            else {
                header("Content-Type: text/html/force-download");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='file_name.xml'");

                $xml = new XMLWriter();

                $xml -> openURI("test.xml");
                $xml -> startDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
                $xml -> setIndent(true);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                    $xml -> startElement("clients");

                    $xml -> writeAttribute('company_name', $row['company_name']);
                    $xml -> writeAttribute('phone', $row['phone']);
                    $xml -> writeAttribute('address', $row['address']);
                    $xml -> writeAttribute('approximate_employees', $row['approximate_employees']);
                    $xml -> writeAttribute('project_code', $row['project_code']);
                    $xml -> writeRaw($row['clients']);

                    $xml -> endElement();
               }

               $xml -> endElement();

               header('Content-type: text/xml');
               $xml -> flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but you have to add more details. Have you errors? In this case, which? Have you double-checked if the query produce results? you obtain a incomplete xml or nothing? etc...

Comment: I neglected to include the html form. While that improved things I'm currently receiving a 'mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /var/www/html/library/php/search.php on line 53' message. I'm still to figure that

Comment: parameter 1 = first arg of the function, so you pass a wrong arg to function: pay attention at your code: what you pass to `mysql_fetch_assoc` ?

Comment: 'Result' instead of 'Results'. That's fixed. Now I'm getting 'Undefined index: clients in /var/www/html/library/php/search.php'

Comment: Undefined index = array with unexisting key. I don't know where, maybe `$row['clients']` ? it exists? client**s**? You can use `var_dump($row)` to see all keys and values of `$row`...

Comment: I've assigned company_name as Primary Key and I'm using print_r($_POST); and I'm getting:

Comment: Array ( [keyword] => Ajax [searchButton] => Search [choice] => company_name )

Comment: table columns are : company_name, phone, address, approximate_employees, project_code

Comment: not `$_POST`, the problem is in `$row[clients]`; `print_r($row)`, in the loop, then `die()` to stop temporary stop loop. BTW, maybe `company_name` instead of `clients`?

Comment: print_r($row) generates:                                                                           Array ( [keyword] => Ajax [searchButton] => Search [choice] => company_name ) Array ( [company_name] => Ajax [phone] => 777-777-7777 [address] => 25 Fake Street [approximate_employees] => 60 [project_code] => AD6

Comment: These are the appropriate format and it creates a file entitled 'test.xml' so I guess its working as it should, though I'd like it to open the file in browser. Thanks for your help